# Calculate the double integral: $\int \int_R \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \ dx \ dy$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Calculate the double integral:

$$\int \int_R \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \ dx \ dy$$

With  the region R  : $ y^2 \leq 8x$ and $y \leq 2x $ and  $ y+4x \leq 24$
So, the problem that I have is about the graph of the region. What I've tried is to write $ y^2 \leq 8x$ as $ y \leq \sqrt{8x}$ . I used  $ y \leq \sqrt{8x}$ and $y \leq 2x $ to try to graph the region .
I' ve attached an image with the graph that I drew . I would like to know if this is the correct graph and also the bounds of $x$.Thank you!
[image]

Comment: $y = -\sqrt{8x}$ should always be your bottom curve. From $x=0$ to $x=2$ your upper curve should be $y=2x$. From $x=2$ to $x=4.5$ it should be $y=\sqrt{8x}$. From $x=4.5$ to $x=8$, the upper curve is $y=24-4x$.

Comment: Remember that square roots grow faster at first than linear functions. Eventually the negatively-sloped line will dominate as well. It may help to find points of intersection and sketch all three curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm your hand sketch, you can use one of the online tools. Some of them are free and are very easy to use. Here is the sketch of your region. You need to find the shaded area. Now if you integrate wrt $y$ first, you have $3$ sub-regions to integrate over but if you integrate over $x$ first, you have only two. So I would suggest setting up your integral as below.

As you can find, the intersection point of parabola $y^2 = 8x$ and line $y = 2x$ is $(2,4)$.

The intersection point of parabola $y^2 = 8x$ and line $y + 4x = 24$ is $(\frac{9}{2},6)$.

Limits of integral -

$\frac{y}{2} \leq x \leq 6 - \frac{y}{4} \,$ for $0 \leq y \leq 4$

$\frac{y^2}{8} \leq x \leq 6 - \frac{y}{4} \,$ for $4 \leq y \leq 6$

Order of Your integral o- first over $dx$ and then $dy$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I should have used   the second linear function for my graph  ......

Comment: You are welcome.